# Trying to install apache on CentOS7 using Chef

Tags: apache, automation, chef-infra

I'm trying to use Chef on CentOS7 and I'm at the beginning ... following the tutorial I0m trying to install apache using this recipe.

```
package 'apache2' do
 action :install
end

service 'apache2' do
 action [:enable, :start]
end

file '/var/www/index.html' do
 content '<html>
           <body>
            <h1>Hello world!!</h1>
           </body>
          </html>'
end
```

When I try to execute I obtain this error ...

```
[osboxes@osboxes chef-repo]$ sudo chef-apply hello.rb 
Recipe: (chef-apply cookbook)::(chef-apply recipe)
  * yum_package[apache2] action install
    * No candidate version available for apache2
    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `install` on resource 'yum_package[apache2]'
    ================================================================================

    Chef::Exceptions::Package
    -------------------------
    No candidate version available for apache2
```

The same if I use a simpler recipe like this

```
package 'apache2'
```

My Chef client workstation installation is the following

```
[osboxes@osboxes chef-repo]$ chef --version
Chef Development Kit Version: 3.0.36
chef-client version: 14.1.12
delivery version: master (7206afaf4cf29a17d2144bb39c55b7212cfafcc7)
berks version: 7.0.2
kitchen version: 1.21.2
inspec version: 2.1.72
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CentOS / RHEL etc (and on Fedora) the package name for Apache is "httpd".

Alternatively, there is a standard cookbook for installing and configuring Apache2:

- https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/apache2

It is fairly sophisticated, and includes recipes for configuring a number of common Apache modules.

Comment: The standard cookbook is `httpd`, not `apache2` :)

Comment: OK ... so there are multiple standards :-).  But my point stands - there is no need to reinvent the wheel.